# Add created objects to List automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a simple class

```
class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

        public Employee() 
        { 
        }

        public static Employee GetNewestEmployee(List<Employee> e)
        {
            Employee emp = e.OrderByDescending(x => x.HireDate).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("The newest employee was hired on {0}",emp.HireDate);
            return emp;
        }
```

The method will return the employee who was most recently hired.  In my Main method I have something like

```
Employee e = new Employee();
            e.EmployeeId = 101;
            e.FirstName = "Tom";
            e.LastName = "Jones";
            e.HireDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(40));

            Employee e2 = new Employee();
            e2.EmployeeId = 102;
            e2.HireDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(100));

            Employee e3 = new Employee();
            e3.EmployeeId = 103;
            e3.HireDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1000));
            List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
            empList.Add(e);
            empList.Add(e2);
            empList.Add(e3);

            Console.WriteLine(Employee.GetNewestEmployee(empList).EmployeeId);

        }
```

all of this works well enough but I was wondering what would the solution be if you didn't know how many Employee objects were going to be created, or there were 1000s of employee objects created.  How can one do something like `foreach(object o thatHasBeenInstantiated)`?

Comment: Answer depends on...question. If you mean: "how can I create N instances?" then answer is "depends where you get your data". If you mean "how can I do something with them if I don't know their number?" then answer is "with a foreach over a *repository*, you can see your List<Employee> as a over-simple in memory database".

Comment: @Adriano Not familiar with the term repository as it pertains to programming, will have to look that one up

Comment: Yes don't solve problems that don't exist. You'll waste time every time.

Comment: My intent was to ask more details...your question isn't clear enough to write a proper answer (without guessing or without writing a tutorial). Do you need to know...how to create multiple instances from a data source of unknown length? Do you need to track when an object is created (then Jay and JG's answers are for you)? Do you need to know how/where store an arbitrary set of objects used through your application?

Comment: My question can be boiled down to the last line: is it possible to do something akin to for each object of a given type that has been instantiated, but these other answers are helpful as well for future learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, some representation of your employee entities would be stored in a database, and you would query that store for scenarios like this.

If you really want to keep all instantiated Employee objects around, you could maintain a static list:

```
public class Employee
{
    private static readonly IList<Employee> _allEmployees = new List<Employee>();

    public Employee()
    {
        // constructor stuff
        _allEmployees.Add(this);
    }
}
```

In this way, it is impossible to instantiate an Employee without it being added to the collection of instances, and your `static NewestEmployee` method (or property) would look at the `_allEmployees` list instead of taking a list as an argument.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking, but I was thinking of having a property of a List<Employee> objects in the class itself and it just didn't seem to be a good idea in my mind, private field would seemingly be better.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into creating an `EmployeeFactory` object to take care of that work for you.

```
public class EmployeeFactory
{
    private readonly IList<Employee> empList;

    public EmployeeFactory(IList<Employee> empList)
    {
        // guard clause to protect from null lists
        this.empList = empList;
    }

    public Employee Create(/* optional employee data used to instatiate */)
    {
        var newEmp = new Employee();
        this.empList.Add(newEmp);
        return newEmp;
    }
}
```

Then where ever you need to create an employee just use the factory and when you need the list you can provided that where needed as well

```
var empList = new List<Employee>();
var empFactory = new EmployeeFactory(empList);

var emp1 = empFactory.Create();
var emp2 = empFactory.Create();
var emp3 = empFactory.Create();

foreach (var emp in empList)
{
    // do stuff w/ each employee
}
```

By creating an employee list and using an `EmployeeFactory` you can provide the factory to code that just needs to create `Employee` objects, or to code that just needs the employee list you can provide just that.  This avoids any static referencing issues that may occur during code reuse.  For example, if you maintain a static list of `Employee` objects within a static member on the `Employee` object, but you don't ever need to worry about the list of employees, that list will continue to grow until the application is terminated.  By maintaining the list separately the application reusing the code can pick and choose how to maintain the employee list.

Comment: Haven't delved fully into the Factory pattern, but this does seem like an advantageous place to use it.

Comment: I don't think this is a use case for the factory pattern. For one, each instance of `EmployeeFactory` that you create is going to have its own list of employees (`empList` should be declared `static` to resolve this). Secondly, using a factory does not really buy you anything that you cannot achieve with normal constructors. Only if you had some compelling reason to keep knowledge of an instance list outside of the `Employee` class might this be desireable. This leaves a gaping opportunity to miss instances by not using the factory somewhere.

Comment: @Jay you provide the exact same instance of the `IList<Employee>` to all of the `EmployeeFactory` objects that you create, and ideally you would only need one `EmployeeFactory` anyway, and that would get created at the composition root of the application.